# Using pkg in nodejs with bootstrap

Tags: json, node.js, bootstrap-4

My question is related to [pkg](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg)

My project strucutre is like this

> node_modules
>
> > bootstrap
> >
> > > dist
> >
> > jquery
> >
> > > dist
> >
> > popper.js
> >
> > > dist
>
> index.html
>   package.json
>   script.js
>   main.js

According to the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pkg#detecting-assets-in-source-code), in package.json, I need to add

```
"pkg": {
"scripts": "build/**/*.js",
"assets": "views/**/*"
}
```

I didn't understand this line:

```
"scripts": "build/**/*.js",
```

In my case should I write something like this ?

```
"scripts": "node_modules/**/dist/*.js",
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved. I added this code in package.json:

```
  "pkg": {
"assets": ["index.html",
  "script.js", "style.css", "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js", "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js", "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js", "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js", "canvasjs/jquery.canvasjs.min.js"
]
```